# Autoclick an onclick event every often

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to make a script to click automatically on that onclick element "training.start_training(50)", but couldn't figure it out how to.

This is the code from the page I want the autoclick:

```
<td style="text-align:center"><img src="/y/training/train.png" onclick="training.start_training(50)" style="cursor:pointer" /></td>
```

And this comes before it, but I don't know if it's actually useful to do this:

form id="trainform" action="" method="post"
input id="trainid" name="trainid" type="hidden" value="0" />

Thanks for the answers. Buuut, I don't know how to write a script, I tried several Frankenstein scripts on greasemonkey (joined several things, kept changing to see if it worked), but got nothing. I don't know how to make an autoclick that clicks on that specified onclick (element?) "training.start_training(50)".

Comment: The Javascript function you are looking for is `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

You can give an id to that image tag or use javascript to get the element by tag name and trigger a click.

```
 var img= document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[0];
setInterval(function(){  img.click(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: And hope that `img` never gets changed anywhere.